# Snapshot of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and overlaid Views

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapture

I have a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on a view with the camera feed and some views above it (buttons, reference lines, etc).

How can I get a snapshot of the app as the user sees it (with the camera image and overlays)?

The window `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` only gets the overlaid views, the view from `drawViewHierarchyInRect:` of the main Screen it's blank, and from `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` I get the camera picture without the overlays.